# Initialize private variables from subclass

Tags: java, private

I have an upcoming exam and one of practice tasks is the following:

My problem with this task is the two private variables name and course.
Private means they cannot be overwritten by the subclasses, right?
How am I supposed to initialize those variables from the subclasses?

This is my code so far, but it does not work:

```
class Bachelor extends Student{
    Bachelor (String n, String c){
        name = n;
        course = c;
    }
    void printlabel() {
        System.out.println("%s\nBachelor %s",name, course);
    }
}
class Master extends Student{
    Master (String n, String c){
        name = n;
        course = c;
    }
    void printlabel() {
        System.out.println("%s\nMaster %s",name, course);
    }
}

public abstract class Student {
    private String name;
    private String course;
    public Student (String n, String c) {
        name = n;
        course = c;
    }
    void printname() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    void printcourse() {
        System.out.println(course);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bachelor rolf = new Bachelor("Rolf", "Informatics");
        rolf.printname();

    }
    abstract void printlabel();
}
```

Detailed description:
Create `class Student` with two private objectvariables `name` and `course`.
Then create a constructor that initializes those variables, the methods `printname()` and `printcourse()` and the astract method `printlabel()`.

Then create two subclasses `Bachelor` and `Master`. They are supposed to have a constructor and overwrite the abstract method.

e.g.

```
Bachelor b = new Bachelor("James Bond", "Informatics");
b.printlabel();
```

Is supposed to return the name, the classname and the course.

Comment: First thing first. In constructor of Bechalor use `super(name, course)`.

Comment: Does your code compile? The constructor of class Student must named Student(..) not Kata

Comment: Also use camelCase in method names `printname` --> `printName`,  `printcourse` --> `printCourse`

Comment: @Jens Thank you for that. Fixed the typo. :)

Comment: @Jens regarding camelCase: I come from Python where it is prefered to use underscores like so: print_name. Is this acceptable in Java or is camelCase the convention?

Comment: Yes ist is the convention in Java. underscores are not acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the superclass constructor with [a call to `super()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html). So in your subclass, just call `super(n, c);` instead of assigning the variables directly and you should get the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me solve the issue. Whatever points I will receive in my exam with this knowledge will be in your honor! :D I would +1 your answer but unfortunately I lack the points for that right now. Will come back later when I have them.

Answer (score 0):

Add a pubic method that sets the private properties. Call said public methods from contructor.